# Broccoli MergeError for .DS_Store file in angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, broccolijs

I am facing this issue when trying to build angular-cli based app.

```
Build failed.
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliMergeTrees] failed with:
Error: Merge error: file .DS_Store exists in /private/var/www/myapp/src/app/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-input_base_path-W89nbkgj.tmp/0 and /private/var/www/myapp/src/app/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-input_base_path-W89nbkgj.tmp/1
Pass option { overwrite: true } to mergeTrees in order to have the latter file win.
    at BroccoliMergeTrees._mergeRelativePath (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:266:17)
    at BroccoliMergeTrees.build (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:70:24)
    at /private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:61:34
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
    at BroccoliMergeTrees.Plugin (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:10:31)
    at new BroccoliMergeTrees (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:30:10)
    at Angular2App._buildTree (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:170:14)
    at new Angular2App (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:53:23)
    at module.exports (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/angular-cli-build.js:10:10)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/builder.js:55:19)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/builder.js:89:10)
    at new Class (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:18:12)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/tasks/build.js:15:19)
    at /private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/ng2/commands/test.js:63:30
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at /private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:331:11
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/private/var/www/myapp/src/app/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Everything was working perfectly until I took 5 - 6 hour development break and then this error appeared. How can I pass `{overwrite: true}` option to Broccoli?

Comment: can you just delete temp folder and rebuild the app.

Comment: Did it many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an issue with `angular-cli` and posted [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1439).

Finally, I found out that at one place where `{overwrite: true}` option was missing when merging nodes.

**Line 170 in angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js**

```
merged = new BroccoliMergeTrees([merged, publicFolder]);
```

changed to

```
merged = new BroccoliMergeTrees([merged, publicFolder], {overwrite: true});
```

and everything is working fine now.

I have [created a PR](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1440) for this but unfortunately, Broccoli is gonna be removed in next angular-cli version.

Comment: File was in the place you said and made the simple change and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and no luck with delete temp folder

What i did is remove .DS_Store recursively
1. Open up Terminal and go into your project folder
2. Finally, in the command line, type:
`find . -name '*.DS_Store' -type f -delete`

https://jonbellah.com/recursively-remove-ds-store/

it worked for me

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did same thing but eventually I found a solution by fixing a bug in `angular-cli`. see my answer below.

Comment: thank you. I was deleted /tmp/ folder and it wasn't working.